# MATLAB: can't get houghlines to detect even a simple line?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, line, hough-transform

I'm learning how `hough` and `houghlines` work in MATLAB but I can't seem to make the example code found in the function's documentation to behave correctly even for a [simple line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lMSg.png) I drew in Paint.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
clear all; clc; close all

I = imread('lines2.png');
BW = im2bw(I);
[H,T,R] = hough(BW,'Theta',-90:0.1:89.99,'RhoResolution',1);
P = houghpeaks(H,2);

lines = houghlines(H,T,R,P,'FillGap',10,'MinLength',1);
figure, imshow(I), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
end
```

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aui0u.png) result (the ends of the lines lie outside the image itself). Anyone else can reproduce it?

I have tried modifying the parameters for `hough` but none of my tests have given the expected result. Actually, setting the `'Theta'` parameter's step to 1 results in not obtaining the line in the right. I have also tried inverting the image with `BW=~BW;` but then I get only a line very far away from the frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For houghlines the first input is BW not H. Use ~BW in your code which makes the line white and the background black. With these changes your code should work correctly.

```
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',10,'MinLength',1);
```

Comment: Oh my God I can't believe I hadn't noticed that! Thank you so much for pointing it out; I guess it's one of those mistakes you just read over and over again until you realize a few days later with a fresh mind. In any case, you saved me some time of hair pulling :D